# Testnet addresses fail in explorers

Tags: testnet, bip44, blockcypher

I've generated a testnet address like this:

```
const btc = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
const bip32 = require('bip32');
const bip39 = require('bip39');

var root = bip32.fromSeed(
    bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync('my-twelve-word-seed...'), 
    btc.networks.testnet
);
var pubkey = root.derivePath("m/44'/1'/0'/0/0").publicKey;
console.log(btc.payments.p2pkh({pubkey}).address);
```

and for my troubles I end up with this value: `14kwGTShacA5hT4uAes7dkNvreuHXuRRf7`

however, when I test that with BlockCypher (or Blockchain.com or some other explorer), it doesn't seem to recognise it:

```
curl https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/addrs/14kwGTShacA5hT4uAes7dkNvreuHXuRRf7/balance
```

yields

> {"error": "Address 14kwGTShacA5hT4uAes7dkNvreuHXuRRf7 incompatible
>   with current block chain: BTC.test3"}

notice that according to BIP44 the derivation path for testnet coins is `m/44'/1'` vs. `m/44/0'` for mainnet

so what is wrong here?

Comment: A chain explorer can only know about addresses which have actually been used in a transaction which has been broadcast over the network. Have you tried sending some testnet coins to the address you generated?

Comment: no, but I should be able to get a zero balance.  the problem isn't with whether the address has been used.  it's a format problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. The address is derived correctly, it is just not encoded with the right version.

You need to add the testnet network version to the `btc.payments.p2pkh` call as well.

Something like this should work:

```
console.log(btc.payments.p2pkh({pubkey, network: btc.networks.testnet}).address);
```

The address should then start with `m...` instead of `1...`.

More information about the available parameters can be found here: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/src/payments/p2pkh.js

Comment: ecco! a million thanks.  right on point